# How to sum up values when the only connection is count?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT Country.NAME, COUNT(Politics.DEPENDENT) as Number_of__dependent_countries
FROM Country
JOIN Politics ON Politics.DEPENDENT = Country.CODE 
GROUP BY Country.NAME;
```

I want to sum up the population(Country.Population) of the countries i counted.

Code to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Politics
(Country VARCHAR(4) CONSTRAINT PoliticsKey PRIMARY KEY,
 Independence DATE,
 WasDependent VARCHAR(40),
 Dependent  VARCHAR(4),
 Government VARCHAR(120));
```

```
CREATE TABLE Country
(Name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
 Code VARCHAR(4) CONSTRAINT CountryKey PRIMARY KEY,
 Capital VARCHAR(40),
 Province VARCHAR(40),
 Area INTEGER CONSTRAINT CountryArea
   CHECK (Area >= 0),
 Population INTEGER CONSTRAINT CountryPop
   CHECK (Population >= 0));
```

Comment: so use `SUM( Country.Population )` ?

Comment: provide sample table data and expected result

Comment: The problem is that the data is pretty big so that it would make no sense to privde sample data.

Comment: If i use sum(Country.Population) i get an error that the value is to big for an integer.

Comment: SUM(CAST(Country.Population AS BIGINT))

Comment: No guys, that would give them the population multiplied with the number of dependent countries.

Comment: BTW: What is your DBMS? Oracle? MySDQL? SQL Server? ... You should always tag your SQL questions with the DBMS you are using. And sample data means: Some sample rows, say five rows, with only the columns of importance here.

Comment: The Insert are to big so that i cannot implement them.

Comment: Erm, are you sure that the `politics` table's primary key is `country`? That wuld be a 1:1 relation and `COUNT(Politics.DEPENDENT)` would always be either 0 or 1. I'd rather expeect a `PRIMARY KEY (COUNTRY, DEPENDENT)`.

Comment: I just copied the create table code form the database.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was confused. While it is strange to have two tables instead of just one then, the count is of course not always 0 or 1. I was mistaken.

Comment: I updated the creates to original ones.

Comment: We still don't know your DBMS. Netbeans is just an IDE. I am removing this tag, because this is unrelated. As well as the database tag, as your request is not on how to build a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You want to get the popultion sum of the dependent countries. The dependent countries are not even joined yet. You must join the country table again:

```
SELECT
  c.name,
  COUNT(*) as number_of_dependent_countries,
  SUM(cd.population) AS population_of_dependent_countries
FROM country c
JOIN politics p ON p.dependent = c.code 
JOIN country cd ON cd.code = p.country
GROUP BY c.name
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5a1a354955464e427952c8c5811fca49

<strike>Original answer:</strike>

You want rows from country plus an aggregation, so either join the aggregation result:

```
SELECT
  c.name, c.population,
  COALESCE(d.countries, 0) AS number_of_dependent_countries
FROM country c
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT dependent, COUNT(*) AS countries
  FROM politics
  GROUP BY dependent
) d ON d.dependent = c.code
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Or use a subquery in the select clause:

```
SELECT
  c.name, c.population,
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM politics p
    WHERE p.dependent = c.code
  ) AS number_of_dependent_countries
FROM country c
ORDER BY c.name;
```

Comment: If i use a subquery i all the time get the message that it only works for 1 row.

Comment: But `COUNT(*)` without `GROUP BY` returns only one row.

Comment: How can i do a multiselect with a subquery?

Comment: Although it seems like your code gives out the population of the country, which the other contries depent on and i want the sum of the population of the countries which are dependent on another.

Comment: For example i got 3 countries which are dependent on the same country, bc they are territory of the other country. With ```Count(Politics.Dependent)``` i get the number of countries which depent on the same one and with sum i want to get the population of all these countries.

Comment: Ah, you want the population sum of the *other* countries! For this to happen you must join the country table again. I've updated my answer. I've added a demo. As you haven't told us your DBMS, I used SQL Server for the demo, but that doesn't really matter, as the query is standard SQL and should run in about every DBMS.